# How to get useful error information from mysql command?

Tags: mysql, errors, command-line

I'm trying to script the creation of a database with tables. I'm encountering errors but the error messages are not helpful to me because I'm a novice.

I'm finding the `mysql` tool is providing mostly useless error messages. It is telling me there's an error but it is not telling me what the error is. `mysql -v` just echos the command, and does not detail the actual error.

My question is, how do I get useful error information from `mysql` command?

---

Here is an example of the script:

```
# Whitelist table
mysql -v -u"${MARIADB_USER}" -p"${MARIADB_PASS}" -e '
    USE '"${MY_DB}"';
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '"${MY_WHITE_TABLE}"'
    ("key" INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "number" VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8);
'
```

Here is an example of the error message:

```
--------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS whitelist
        ("key" INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "number" VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8)
--------------

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
nual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
 near '"key" INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "number" VARCHAR(20) CHARA
CTER SE' at line 2
```

---

I've tried leaving the column name unquoted, single quoting the column name, and double quoting the column name. At this point I believe the problem lies elsewhere, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting of column names and table names (and some other things) is with backtics:

```
(`key` INT ...
```

You can change that with a `sql_mode`, but MySQL users rarely do that.

In the long run, I think you will abandon using shell scripts to run MySQL commands.

Comment: Thanks. How can I get a useful error message from the tool? That appears to be my biggest problem. (Experienced users probably don't suffer the problem).

Comment: When using a language (Perl, Java, PHP, VB, etc), you get the resultsets and errors and can act on them.

Comment: Thanks again. @Rick. I tried to switch to a [`*.sql` file](https://pastebin.com/VFqcmrvT). Unfortunately I can't get the damn thing to work. Even something as simple as using a variable is broken. How do you database guys work with these crappy tools?

Comment: @jww - More details, please.  As for "crappy tools" -- they know to pick on _you_.

Comment: I'm am absolutely baffled one cannot get useful error messages from this tool. It is absolute junk. I would be embarrassed to publish a tool as broken as this (and I am a C/C++/ObjC programmer).

Comment: If you have an account at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), then the question from the pastebin is at [Incorrect syntax near '@DB_DATABASE_NAME'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/501694/56041). I cannot believe how much time I have wasted on these simple problems because of that tool.

Comment: Now open in the MySQL Issue Tracker: [Issue 94398, mysql provides useless error messages](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94398). Oracle should be ashamed of themselves.

Comment: @jww - It also helps to carefully read the syntax description in the manual.  Double quotes are not allowed unless you set an particular option; did you 'invent' the use of `"` around `key`?  Database names must be actual names, not @variables.  Error 1064 is very good at pointing to exactly where the problem is (except for unbalanced quotes).